# Car Return Problem

Tags: cipher

Dave planned a party for his new company. Hundreds of people were invited and he knew that car parking would be a problem. To make it easier, the staff were to park the cars by brand and size.

On the night of the party six cars were exactly the same! How were they going to give the cars back to the right owner?

> Using the license plates and names figure out which car goes to who.

```
A)Edward        1)B144 SFX
B)Steven        2)T113 VFM
C)Andrew        3)B147 FMB
D)Samuel        4)F423 BSE
E)Thomas        5)T205 WFO
F)Angela        6)U815 NBT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Edward  - F423 BSE
>  Steven - T205 WFO
>  Andrew - B144 SFX
>  Samuel - T113 VFM
>  Thomas - U815 NBT
>  Angela - B147 FMB
>  Each license plate has the letters transposed by 1 (A -> B etc), and the numbers are the letter's index in the alphabet (A = 1, B = 2 etc).

Comment: Put text between paragraphs to keep spoiler formatting

Comment: Thanks, had an extra space somewhere so it messed up the syntax...

Comment: Nice job! As you can tell, I just created an account and this is my first time

Answer (score 1):

The cars go to:

> 1 -> Andrew 
>  2 -> Steven 
>  3 -> Angela
>  4 -> Edward
>  5 -> Samuel
>  6 -> Thomas

Reasoning:

> Start with Andrew and Angela, they must have the first 2 letters the same. An observation is that licence plates have 7 letters whereas the names have 6, so in each name 2 letters on the licence plate is combined. 
>  We find that (1) and (3) have the first three characters. So we conclude that "B" in the license plate is an "A" and that "14" is an "N", we observe that it must be in this way since (3) ends in a B so this one must be Angela's. 
>  A N G E L A = B 14 7 F M B 
>  A N D R E W = B 14 4 S F X 
>  so we can confirm that F is E based on the placements 
>  Edward is the only one that starts with "E" so he is (4) 
>  Steven and Samuel start with S. So that narrows it down to (2) or (5) Steven has and "E" before last which is "F" so Steven has car (2) and Samuel has car (5) leaving thomast with car (6)